# Spring MVC Controller not resolving URI

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

This is a similar question to those that have been asked before, but still different, and I simply can't figure it out.

I have a controller for a REST webservice implemented with MVC which should be handling requests for the path '/users/contacts', the problem is that in my client test app, when I try to hit that path I get:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI /users/users/contacts in DispatcherServlet with name 'webservice'
```

Again, in my client test app, when I change the request path to something like '/WHATEVERusers/contacts', I'll get an error that it can't resolve '/WHATEVERusers/contacts'

I don't know why when I try to hit a path handled by a controller it get's mangled, but when I request some garbage path, it doesn't.

I don't have the code in front of me, but will be able to answer questions when I get home.

Here's code from my test client:

```
private static void TestGetContacts()
{
    UserCreateRequest request = new UserCreateRequest();

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try

    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        StringEntity string  = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(request), HTTP.UTF_8);
        string.setContentType("application/json");

        URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "localhost", 8888, "/users/contacts", null, null);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
        post.setEntity(string);

        client.execute(post);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here's my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users/contacts")
public class UserContactService
{
private @Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public GetContactsResponse GetContacts(@RequestBody UserCreateRequest request)
{
    GetContactsResponse response = new GetContactsResponse();

    return response;
}
}
```

Here's my servlet config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<!--
    - The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation.
-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.impersonal.server.restservice.users"/>                

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            <!-- 
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
            <ref bean="atomConverter" />
            -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

And here's my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/**/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Update:**
My requests are handled in my controller, but after the request is handled, the server prints out that it couldn't resolve /users/users/contacts.  For some reason another request is getting to DispsatcherServlet, and I don't know why..

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Without more information, it's hard tell if the problem is in your client or in your web service. Post more details about your client test app, or take client confusion out of the picture by using a simple HTTP client such as cURL. Also post more details about your web service, including how you configure it to handle specific URLs.

Comment: Can you please provide the servlet-mapping for your Dispatcher Servlet, and the webapplications context name also - is either of these /users by any chance. Also, how have you initialized Spring MVC, is it just using mvc:annotation-driven or have you customized the handleradapter or handler mapping in any way

Comment: can you share your controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `@ResponseBody` to my method signature solved my issue.  Didn't realize I actually needed it, and not having it resulted in really odd side affects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the url in the @RequestMapping above your method instead of above your Class? I've noticed that it might solve URI Mapping issues from time to time.

You could handle more urls with different methods in the same class. You could even add @RequestMapping("/users") above your Class and add different methods with

- @RequestMapping("/contacts") maps to /users/contacts
- @RequestMapping("/customers") maps to /users/customers